# Identação SASS 2 espaços?

Tags: css, sass

Olá,

Recentemente estou utilizando o Sass sem nenhum automatizador front-end devido às diretrizes da empresa e costumo trabalhar com o formato .sass, porém ando tendo problemas com as identações do mesmo, sempre reclamando que ao invés de um tab, são dois espaços... como faço para corrigir isso?

*Já vi um post gringo ensinando a corrigir, porém não encontrei no meu computador o arquivo que ele editou.
**Uso Windows

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689264/change-indentation-in-sass

Answer (score 1):

O [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) é um plugin para o seu editor que permite a preparação do seu editor para obedecer a configuração do seu projeto, respeitando assim espaçamento, tab, novas linhas e tudo mais o que você definir no arquivo de configuração. Você pode utilizar com o Sublime Text, Visual Code e etc..

Depois de instalar o plugin do [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/), adicione o arquivo `.editorconfig` com a seguinte configuração:

```
root = true

# General
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# Indentation of Stylesheets
[*.{sass, scss, css}]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

Comment: onde coloco o arquivo .editorconfig? Instalei o plugin no Sublime via package control.

Comment: Você pode adicionar na pasta root do seu projeto.